# Error: Unknown Column cnt in 'field list' - mysql stored preocedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to make simple test for while loop in stored procedure from this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx)
I faced this error

```
 Unknown Column cnt  in 'field list'
```

here is the sp, can somebody help?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `WhileLoopProc` ()

BEGIN

    DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 1;

    DECLARE str VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';

    WHILE cnt  <  10 DO

       SET str = CONCAT(str,cnt,',');

       set cnt = cnt + 1 ;

    END WHILE;
SELECT str;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: But it is working fine [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8297d/2)?

Comment: Mmm MySQL version I had is 5.5.16, do you think it's versions problem?

Comment: How are you calling the procedure?

Comment: call test.WhileLoopProc() because I run it inside the test schema

Comment: Same problem with repeat until example!

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal, here is the error occur in this example
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5643b/1

Comment: @palAlaa - I don't know really why. It is a weird thing. Note that if I replaced the `UNTIL` loop with `WHILE` it works fine [like in this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f864e/1) with output `null` , because the `str` wasn't initialized, if you intialize it you will got the proper output [like this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84c50/1), please update your question with these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a no-break space character (U+00A0) immediately after your variable name in the following line:

```
    WHILE cnt  <  10 DO
             ^--- this is U+00A0
```

MySQL does not recognise such characters as whitespace, but rather as part of the variable name.

Comment: Incredible problem  and incredible problem solving. Thanks a milion